# Cannot access offset of type string on string, get specific part from array. PHP

Tags: php, json

Can some one help me with this problem? i want to get every prefix from every server.

My error: `Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string in test.php:67 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\GameServer Status\test.php on line 67`

```
  // JSON string
  $someJSON = https://api.gametools.network/bf1/servers/?name=lo&lang=en-us&region=all&platform=pc&limit=2 (in a URL because of space)

  // Loop through Array
  $someArray = json_decode($someJSON['servers'], true); // Replace ... with your PHP Array
  foreach ($someArray as $key => $value) {
    echo $value["prefix"];
  }

?>
```

Comment: remember, json is in this case in url because i have no more space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, the `$someJSON` in your example is just a string containing the URL, you need to call that URL to get the JSON from the API, this can be done easily with the `file_get_contents` function.

After that, you can decode that JSON with `json_decode` and then iterate over the **servers**.

```php
$someJSON = file_get_contents('https://api.gametools.network/bf1/servers/?name=lo&lang=en-us&region=all&platform=pc&limit=2');

$someArray = json_decode($someJSON, true);

foreach ($someArray['servers'] as $key => $value) {
    echo $value["prefix"] . "\n";
}
```

Optionally you could also use cURL to grab the JSON.

```php
$someJSON = curl_init('https://api.gametools.network/bf1/servers/?name=lo&lang=en-us&region=all&platform=pc&limit=2');

curl_setopt_array($someJSON, [
    CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
]);

$someArray = json_decode(curl_exec($someJSON), true);

curl_close($someJSON);

foreach ($someArray['servers'] as $key => $value) {
    echo $value["prefix"] . "\n";
}
```

Comment: is curl faster?

Comment: Don't know if it's faster, it might be. I'll add a curl option to my answer as well.

Comment: no thanks is not necessary

Comment: what if I now output this code for every server, how would that work?

code; <div >
            <div class="col-sm-12 result-battlefield mt-20">
            <div class="re-costom-sm-3">
                <img src="' .$value['url'] . '" class="img-result">
            </div>
            <div class="result-costom-sm-10" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                <h4>' .$value['prefix'] . '</h4>
                <p>' .$value['serverInfo'] . ' - ' .$value['mode'] . '</p>
                <p>' .$value['platform'] . ' - ' .$value['region'] . '</p>
            </div>
        </div>'

Comment: now it just outputs one

Comment: You add the HTML you want each server to have in the `foreach` loop, In this [gist](https://gist.github.com/thinkverse/26b9dca530fab6ee4a762729ae4c8652) I'm using heredoc since it's a bit cleaner than single or double-quotes.

Comment: uff bro, thanks, finaly i goted.

Comment: thanks for your work, i really appreciated. You now in my contry the clock is 00.30 